# How to get access to documents and videos in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, media-library

Iam an windows phone developer.I am working on accessing device functionalities.I am having media library which can allow access to pictures and songs. I know there is no access to videos. but i need to know Is there any way to access documents in device? and also Is there any way to access videos in the device?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to access documents or videos, with the current API's. You are only able to access the local-storage in which you can save files/videos from within your app.